# Which $L \subset [0,1]$ equal the set of limits of a sequence of a sequence in $[0,1] \setminus L$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

I was glanced at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952570/example-of-an-a-n-sequence-with-exactly-k-limit-points) here and it cause me to wonder the following:

> **Question:** Is there a simple description of the subsets $L \subset [0,1]$ with the property that there exists a sequence  in $[0,1] \setminus L$ whose limit points are exactly $L$?

A few things are pretty easy to see

- Any finite nonempty $L$ has this property.
- Some strange sets have this property. For instance, I think you can get the Cantor set from, say, an enumeration of the midpoints of the intervals deleted during the "take out the middle thirds" construction.

Anyway, I thought it might be a fun problem to find a precise description.

Comment: You should convince yourself that the set of all limit points of a sequence (or of any set, for that matter) is always closed.  I think that every closed set can be thusly characterized.

Comment: I agree that the set of limit points is closed, but the requirement that the sequence stay out of $L$ prevents you from getting any set containing an interval.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I guess it could just be all closed sets $L \subset [0,1]$ with dense complement...?

Comment: I forgot about the "staying out of $L$" requirement, this is interesting after all.  I think that your characterization is correct.  Another way of putting this is that $L$ must be a closed, measure-zero set (I might have to double check that, though).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Actually those don't mean the same thing. For instance, if $q_1,q_2,\ldots$ are the rational points in $[0,1]$ and you delete an open interval of length $(1/2)^{n+1}$ around each $q_n$, then you are left with a closed set of positive measure whose complement is dense.

Comment: I'm aware that sequences have measure zero.  I'm saying that if a closed set (i.e. the set of limit points) has a dense complement, then it must have measure zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Your last statement is precisely what I'm disagreeing with. Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265072/uncountable-closed-set-of-irrational-numbers?lq=1) for more info.

Comment: Omno... is right: you get exactly all closed sets. To obtain a given closed set as the set of limit points, just pick a countable dense subset.

Comment: @MikeF ah, you're right.

Comment: @ChristianRemling The sequence must be disjoint from the set, so a countable subset does not work.